# How to open allure from gradle tasks?

Tags: node.js, gradle, allure

I am very new to gradle and trying to write a gradle task to generate and open allure report. I am trying to use gradle node plugin(com.moowork.node) to use the "allure-commandline" nodejs package. The report runs fine when I have a custom node script but not when doing the same thing from gradle from the default allure-commandline script.The report process I think works in background and thus ie does not open.

```
task allure(type: NodeTask){
    script =file('node_modules/allure-commandline/index.js')
    args = ["allure","generate","allureResults","--clean","-o","allureReport"]
   args = ["allure","open","allureReport"]
}
```

This Node task works:

```
task nodeAllure(type: NodeTask){
    script =file('allure.js')
}
```

My allure.js:

```
var allure = require('allure-commandline');

// returns ChildProcess instance
var generation = allure(['generate', 'reports/allure-results','--clean','-o','allure-report']);

generation.on('exit', function(exitCode) {
    allure(['open','allure-report']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Allure Gradle plugin available that will handle all the work for you. See the docs for more details https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_gradle_3